# Appling a custom function to each row in a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a bit of code which pulls the latitude and longitude for a location. It is here:

```
address = 'New York University'
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'

response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response[0]["lat"])
print(response[0]["lon"])
```

I'm wanting to apply this as a function to a long column of "address".

I've seen loads of questions about 'apply' and 'map', but they're almost all simple math examples.

Here is what I tried last night:

```
def locate (address):
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    print(response[0]["lat"])
    print(response[0]["lon"])
    return

df['lat'] = df['lat'].map(locate)
df['lon'] = df['lon'].map(locate)
```

This ended up just applying the first row lat / lon to the entire csv.

What is the best method to turn the code into a custom function and apply it to each row?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thank you @PacketLoss for your assistance. I'm getting an indexerror:list index out of range, but it does work on his sample dataframe.

Here is the read_csv I used to pull in the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\CIHAnalyst1\\Desktop\\InstitutionLocations.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode', encoding = "utf-8",  warn_bad_lines=False)
```

Here is a text copy of the rows from the dataframe:

```
address
```

0   GRAND CANYON UNIVERSITY
1   SOUTHERN NEW HAMPSHIRE UNIVERSITY
2   WESTERN GOVERNORS UNIVERSITY
3   FLORIDA INTERNATIONAL UNIVERSITY - UNIVERSITY ...
4   PENN STATE UNIVERSITY UNIVERSITY PARK
... ...
4292    THE ART INSTITUTES INTERNATIONAL LLC
4293    INTERCOAST - ONLINE
4294    CAROLINAS COLLEGE OF HEALTH SCIENCES
4295    DYERSBURG STATE COMMUNITY COLLEGE COVINGTON
4296    ULTIMATE MEDICAL ACADEMY - NY

Comment: You are returning nothing, so nothing will be mapped or applied to your dataframe.

Comment: The original bit of code works and does pull in the correct lat / long. I would just like Python to run that code on each location in my csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your values from your function, or nothing will happen.

We can use apply here and pass the address from the `df` as well.

```
data = {'address': ['New York University', 'Sydney Opera House', 'Paris', 'SupeRduperFakeAddress']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def locate(row):
    url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(row['address']) +'?format=json'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if response:
        row['lat'] = response[0]['lat']
        row['lon'] = response[0]['lon']
    return row

df = df.apply(locate, axis=1)
```

---

Outputs

```
                 address           lat                 lon
0    New York University   40.72925325  -73.99625393609625
1     Sydney Opera House  -33.85719805  151.21512338473752
2                  Paris    48.8566969           2.3514616
3  SupeRduperFakeAddress           NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: Interesting. This worked on the dataframe you made, but when I apply it to my csv I get a index error on row['lat'] = response[0]["lat"].

Is there maybe a result it couldn't pull which is causing this?

Comment: Could you include an example of your dataframe after importing from the csv?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the read_csv line of code and an image of what the dataframe looks like. Thank you again.

Comment: Not to be a pain, could you quickly add a text copy of the df instead of an image :)?

Comment: Pasted it in, but not sure that's what you meant :/ I'm the one being the pain! I so appreciate your help! It's so close!

Comment: @CIHAnalytics Updated answer. Issue was if an address was not found `response` is an empty list. We just need to check a response is received prior to accessing index 0

Comment: That did it! AMAZING, THANKS SO MUCH.